# Send update notification to particular users using socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io, mean-stack

Following is the code on front end, where `storeSelUserId` contains user_id to send the message-

**FYI** - Node Version 1.1.0

```
// Socket Notification
var socket = io('http://localhost:6868');
socket.on('connection', function (data) {
    socket.emit('send notification', { sent_to: storeSelUserId });
});
```

Following is the server code in routes file -

```
var clients = {};  
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('connection', "Connection Created.");
  socket.on('send notification', function (sent_to) {
    console.log(sent_to);
  });
});
```

In console `sent_to` is showing the array of `user_id`.

Now being a starter in `socket.io` I stuck with the solution that how do I send the message to these particular userids.

I search and found that I need to push each user with its sockets so I reformed it to -

```
var users = [];  
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  users.push({socket_id: socket.id});
  socket.emit('connection', "Connection Created.");
  socket.on('send notification', function (sent_to) {
    console.log(sent_to);
  });
});
```

But I am in dilemma that else do I need to do to store which `user_id` refers to which socket_id and then update the div of users with that particular ids?

**EDIT** -

**Add Controller - (Front End)**

**Front end Interface where memo is created and send to particular users**

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:6868');
socket.on('connection', function (data) {
    socket.emit('send memo notification', {creator_id: creator_id, sent_to: [Array of user_ids to whom memo to send]});
});
```

**Dashboard controller - (Front End)**

**Front end Interface where notification count to show "notificationCount"**

```
if (SessionService.currentUser._id) {
    var socket = io('http://localhost:6868');
    socket.on('connection', function (data) {
        socket.emit('get notifications', {user_id: SessionService.currentUser._id});
    });

    socket.on('notification data', function(data){
        console.log("-- Not Data Test -");
        $scope.notificationCount = data.length;
    });
}
```

**Code at server end -**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('connection', "Connection Created.");

  socket.on('send memo notification', function(data) {
        notifications.createNotification(data);
  });

  socket.on('get notifications', function(data){
    notifications.getNotifications(data, function(response){
        socket.emit('notification data', response.data);
    });
  });

});
```

**Backend controller code** -

```
exports.getNotifications = function(data, callback) {
    var userId = data.user_id;
    Notification.find({receiver_id: userId}, function(err, response){
        if (err)
            callback({"message": "error", "data": err, "status_code": "500"});
        else
            callback({"message": "success", "data": response, "status_code": "200"});
    });  
};

exports.createNotification = function(data) {
    var notificationData = data;
    var x = 0;
    for(var i=0; i< notificationData.length; i++) {
        // Code
        Notification(notificationData[i]).save(function(err,response){
            if (err)
                return false;
        });    
        if (x === notificationData.length - 1) {
            return true;
        }
        x++;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use your own user ids then there is no way around mapping the socket id to the user id. I assume a client knows its user id from somewhere, so it could send its user id to the server after connection.

Client

```
socket.on('connection', function (data) {
    socket.emit('setUserId', myUserId);
});
```

The server saves the socket for each user id.

```
socket.on('setUserId', function (userId) {
    users[userId]=socket;
});
```

If you have such a mapping in the server you can send a message just to this client using the user id.

```
socket.on('send notification', function (userId) {
     users[userId].emit('notification', "important notification message");
});
```

Edit: Saving the corresponding socket directly is even better.

Comment: Please find my edit..I am not getting automatic update on client side..I have to refresh browser then only update reflects

Answer (score 3):

According to what i understand, you need private notification send to only some users. For that, save your users name to whom you want to send and their corresponding socket in different hashes.

```
username [socket.name] = username to be added;
usersocket [ socket.name ] =socket;
```

Then to emit the messages to that user only, use

```
usersocket[ socket.name ].emit('event for send message', ' what you want to send ');
```

Comment: yeah sure let me just bind files for you

Comment: I saw your edit but I dont see any mistake in it. Try using connect instead of connection coz connection is a reserved event. And don't forget to change the event name in server too.